# Excel file imports - data type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel-interop, winforms-interop

I have been working on a desktop application and I have a little problem with Excel file imports.

Everything is good but when I read the data from the Excel sheet it does not read all the numbers and Alphabets.  For example, if the first cell of the column is numbers then it will not read Alphabets from that column.  If I change the type to Text for that column manually then everything is good.

Here is my sample code for importing Excel sheet data.

Any ideas?

```
public static DataSet exceldata(string filelocation)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    string excelConnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 4.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Importmixedtypes=text;typeguessrows=0;\"", filelocation);

    OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);

    excelConn.Open();

    DataTable dtPatterns = new DataTable();
    excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConn);

    excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;

    excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtPatterns);

    ds.Tables.Add(dtPatterns);

    return ds;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  System.out.println(cell.toString());//here is the problem
> ```

toString() method returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

Use  `cell.getStringCellValue()`

instead

> cell.toString()

And propor usage needed.

For numeric values you have to use

getNumericCellValue() and put a condition there

```
if(cell!=null)
            {
                int type = cell.getCellType();
                if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                  System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)

                  String[] splits = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).split(".");

               System.out.println(splits[0]);
                else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
                    System.out.println( cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                    System.out.println(cell.getColumnIndex() + "] = BLANK CELL");
            }
```